Gitlab : Uploading artifacts as "dotenv" to coordinator failed with TLS handshake
I have created a pipeline with 3 stages. I am storing the each pipeline stage status in "build.env" file.
While executing the pipeline, the build stage script successfully executed but when gitlab tried to upload the "dotenv" artifact that time it fails intermittently with TLS handshake error.
Below is the sample pipeline script.
stages:
  - download
  - build
  - test

download:
  stage: download
  script:
    - echo "===== Download starts ====="
    - echo "===== Download Ends ====="
  after_script:
     # Preserve a job status 'success or failed' into artifacts.
   - >
     if [ $CI_JOB_STATUS == 'success' ]; then
       echo "DOWNLOAD_JOB_STATUS=success" >> build.env
     else
       echo "DOWNLOAD_JOB_STATUS=failed" >> build.env
     fi
  tags:
    - linux
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "===== Build starts ====="
    - echo "===== Build Ends ====="
  after_script:
     # Preserve a job status 'success or failed' into artifacts.
   - >
     if [ $CI_JOB_STATUS == 'success' ]; then
       echo "BUILD_JOB_STATUS=success" >> build.env
     else
       echo "BUILD_JOB_STATUS=failed" >> build.env
     fi
  tags:
    - linux
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "===== Test starts ====="
    - echo "===== Test Ends ====="
  after_script:
     # Preserve a job status 'success or failed' into artifacts.
   - >
     if [ $CI_JOB_STATUS == 'success' ]; then
       echo "TEST_JOB_STATUS=success" >> build.env
     else
       echo "TEST_JOB_STATUS=failed" >> build.env
     fi
  tags:
    - linux
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env

Error Message:

ERROR: Uploading artifacts as "dotenv" to coordinator... error
error=couldn't execute POST against
https://gitlab.abc.com/api/v4/jobs/12345/artifacts?artifact_format=gzip&artifact_type=dotenv:
Post
"https://gitlab.abc.com/api/v4/jobs/12345/artifacts?artifact_format=gzip&artifact_type=dotenv":
net/http: TLS handshake timeout id=12345 token=XXXXXX

How I can fix this issue?
